# Is it faster to proxypass to remove an ending / or is it quicker using php?

Tags: php, performance, nginx

long story short, I'm cleaning an API possessing routes like `/brand/` and `/users` and I was thinking of removing finishing slash, to not break the legacy code I found 2 solutions:

-redirecting using nginx proxypass

-removing the finishing slash before the route handler

The issue is that I know how to test php speed but I have absolutely no idea how to test nginx :/

Comment: nginx will be faster, and the difference will be so minimal it's unlikely it will ever matter.

Comment: @Evert On the high-loaded systems the difference can be quite significant.